# Read in a databse table but only get one field

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datasource

I have a table with four text fields but when I execute the following I only get one field in the DataGridview. I am not geting all the records either I dont think. How to fix it so I get all the fields and records? text= table name this is in a function/method. Is it the query thats fouling things up?

```
   string connetionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\temp\\Set.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";
                string sql = "SELECT Property, PValue, PDefault, PType FROM "+text;
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
                OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                connection.Open();
                dataadapter.Fill(ds, text);
                connection.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
                dataGridView1.DataMember = text;
```

Comment: Did you try using a `DataGridView` instead of a ListView? If I'm not mistaken, in a ListView, you'll have to populate the columns on your own

Comment: The code shows its a datagridview yes its a DataGridView @Larstech thanks changed the question.

Comment: Try putting brackets around [Property].  That's probably a keyword and might be interfering with your query.

Comment: @LarsTech, in that case it would throw a syntax error and won't just fetch single field as OP says

Comment: @Rahul I'm just throwing ideas at him. Nothing obvious from the code that was presented.

Comment: it was "select * From" + text which is more precise

Comment: What "field" are you getting in the DataGridView?  `I am not geting all the records either I dont think.`  You have to know this in order to debug your problem.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on connection.Close() and inspect the data the ds has, then you'll know where the problem actually is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a myriad of things that could be wrong.  But none of them are evidenced in your question.

Your `DataGridView` might not have the correct columns added, or doesn't have `AutoGenerateColumns = true`.

You haven't mentioned if the data is actually missing from the dataset, or if it's just your view that's broken. Wouldn't you KNOW you're not getting all the records back?  Not just have a hunch?  Breakpoint that line, Sir!

Have you tried running that command directly on the database?  Are the results good there?

I expect the answer will be that the data is fine, but the view is not showing all the data, Data...

Comment: Delete the man made colums in the datagridView and add the line    datagridviiew,AutoGenerateColumns = true; Fixed thanks